# Histogram: Format issue

Tags: histograms

I have a format issue with my histogram.

First of all my command:

```
Labeled [Histogram[{data},{Width},"Probability",LabelingFunction->Above,ImageSize->{820,530},PlotRange->All],{Rotate["relative",90 Degree],nameAxisX},{Left,Bottom}]
```

I have data in the interval [0,1] which I have grouped in classes with `Width = 0,1`.

The data are counted correctly. Unfortunately the histogram doesn't start at `0.0` and it extends by `1.0`; or - most surely - it is moved to right so that it looks like it is extending.

I have attached my diagramme so that you will see what I am speaking about.

What I would like to have: every bar of the histogram in its own interval from `0.0-0.1`, `0.1-0.2`, ..., `0.9-1.0`.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: What do you get in return from `MinMax[data]`?

Comment: for min = 0.21 and for max 1.  please see that i have just 1. and not 1.0

Comment: I believe the bins are created in the following manner:  0 <= x < 0.1, 0.1 <= x < 0.2, ...., 0.9 <= x < 1, and 1 <= x < 1.1.  So all of the 1's go into the rightmost bin.  Knocking those 1's down to 0.999 is one way to get the desired histogram.

Comment: oh ok i see that could be the case. yes you are right i have several values with 1.   have you a hint to manipulate the series pretty easily to map all the 1.0 down to 0.999...many thanks

Answer (score 7):

The bins include the left boundary of the bin but not the right boundary.  Therefore, in this case the 1's get moved over to a bin to the right of 1.

```
(* Generate some data from a beta distribution *)
data = RandomVariate[BetaDistribution[10, 0.5], 100];
(* Add some 1's *)
data = Flatten[{data, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}];

(* Resulting histogram *)
Labeled[Histogram[data, {0, 1.1, 0.1}, "Probability",
  LabelingFunction -> Above, ImageSize -> {820, 530}, 
  PlotRange -> All],
 {Rotate["relative", 90 Degree], "X"}, {Left, Bottom}]
```

[image: Original histogram]

Truncating to something like 0.999 will force all of the 1's into the bin just to the left of 1.0:

```
Labeled[Histogram[Map[Min[#, 0.999] &, data], {0, 1, 0.1}, 
  "Probability",
  LabelingFunction -> Above, ImageSize -> {820, 530}, 
  PlotRange -> All],
 {Rotate["relative", 90 Degree], "X"}, {Left, Bottom}]
```

[image: Histogram with ones in the desired bin]

Comment: many thanks. It works perfectly . The MAP-function has been unknown to me

Comment: It maps all numbers bigger than 0.999 to 0.999.  But that might be a bit dangerous if there are wrong or right numbers bigger than one.  If you want just to correct the 1's, then maybe something like `Map[If[# == 1, 0.999, #] &, data]` would be better.  And `data /. {1 -> 0.999}` works, too.

Comment: Many thanks. The data will NEVER be bigger then 1.0 due this are a similarity coefficient and it the upper bound ist 100% . but i will write down your note to my book to have this all in my mind :)

Comment: Never say never.  Things happen.

Answer (score 0):

A complementary approach to @Jim Baldwin's answer would be to slightly increase the size of the last bin instead of manipulating the data:

```
(* Generate some data from a beta distribution *)
data = RandomVariate[BetaDistribution[10, 0.5], 100];
(* Add some 1's *)
data = Flatten[{data, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}];
```

Define the bins (I guess this can be made more elegant, but it's straightforward enough for the current purpose):

```
Width = Join[Table[i, {i, 0, 0.9, 0.1}], {1.0001}];
```

Then your plot:

```
Labeled[Histogram[{data}, {Width}, "Probability", 
  LabelingFunction -> Above, ImageSize -> {820, 530}, 
  PlotRange -> All], {Rotate["relative", 90 Degree], 
  nameAxisX}, {Left, Bottom}]
```

produces

[image]

where the rightmost bins' size is visually undistinguishable from the other ones.